# Get file contents in Joomla

Tags: php, linux, file, joomla, permissions

I'm trying to get a file's content into a variable but I don't get anything when I read the file. I used both methods `JFile::read()` and `file_get_contents()` but both return the same thing: a blank string, not an error , not any boolean values or anything.

I want to mention that I'm working on a Linux machine (just for 2 days) and recently I changed the permissions for the entire machine to 777 ( I don't know if this affects something or not).

Is the a connection between my OS, permissions and the php's `file_get_contents()`? or Joomla restricts file reading?

Also I want to mention that my `file_get_contents()` function was added manually by me in the `index.php` file , also the file I want to read was manually added in the same folder with `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem with one of our clients, it turned out it was a firewall issue. It was very hard to debug this issue. I suggest you check with your networking team.

I am assuming, of course, that you have set the PHP error reporting level to the maximum and that you have checked the error logs.

Comment: It seemed that the file_get_contents return false (no data) so I got a little bit confused. The problem occurred because I messed the entire Linux machine, so I have to re-install it.In other words the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed the problem was from my system . I messed it up when I changed the permissions so I have to re-install it.

**Never change the permissions on a Linux for the entire file system.**